# Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0

Tags: android

here is my code:
help me please

```
dependencies {

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['.jar'])`enter code here`
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: switch to androidx jetpack libraries. https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate. also use implementation instead of deprecated compile if you are using the newer gradle version.

Comment: i'm newbie, so i can't understand. can you give me code ?

Comment: Or you can edit my code

Comment: look at the link posted in the previous comment. follow the android docs.

Comment: ok, i will try. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

// Migrate Your Project To AndroidX After Completing Your Dependencies Look Like This

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.package.name"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

Comment: This Is Just A Sample Dependency Of AndroidX... So Just Migrate Your Project To AndroidX & You Also Get Like This Kind Of Output... Im Using Java & Kotlin

Comment: oh, i understanded. ths you